# How to Encrypt Spring Liquibase Password

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I am new to Liquibase. I have gotten the hang of what I need to do for now. But I would like to know is there a way to encrypt the password we store in the property `spring.liquibase.password` in the `application.properties` file of a Spring Boot application?

Comment: You could use something like [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/), but then you need to store the encryption password somewhere.

Comment: I am already using `jasypt-spring-boot-starter` for my normal database connections. Is it possible to extend is to the liquibase properties?